# How to make emmet.vim plugin work?

Tags: vim, plugins, vi, pathogen

I am really getting headache from this - I am beginning to use `vim` for my daily programming tasks, so I decided to make use of great plugins which are available for it. So I started with [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) and I believe I succesfully installed it. Then I tried [emmet.vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/) but I am really not able make this work. This is my directory structure

```
├── autoload
│   └── pathogen.vim
└── bundle
    ├── autoload
    │   ├── emmet
│       │   ├── lang
│   │       │   ├── css.vim
│   │   │       ├── haml.vim
    │   │   │   ├── html.vim
    │   │   │   ├── sass.vim
    │   │   │   ├── scss.vim
    │   │   │   └── slim.vim
    │   │   ├── lang.vim
    │   │   ├── lorem
    │   │   │   ├── en.vim
│       │   │   └── ja.vim
│   │       └── util.vim
    │   └── emmet.vim
    ├── doc
│       └── emmet.txt
    └── plugin
        └── emmet.vim
| .vimrc
```

And `.vimrc` content

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

So is this right? And I then tried simple tutorial mentioned on GitHub page but it didn't work. So I did

```
vim file.html
i //insert mode
html:5 and then pressing Ctrl + y + ,
```

but nothing happened. I appreciate any advice on this, I got really stucked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot the root directory.

You have `bundle/<repo content>`, but it should be `bundle/emmet-vim/<repo content>`.

So usually you just do:

`$ cd ~/.vim/bundle`

`$ git clone git@github.com:mattn/emmet-vim.git`

(Which is also described at [Pathogen README](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/blob/master/README.markdown) :-))

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as Petr Mensik (except I properly cloned the emmet repo into my bundle directory as described). My .vimrc starts with `execute pathogen#infect()` and pathogen automatically detects the other plugin I have in my bundle directory. I tried the same test as Petr Mensik both in insert mode and normal mode but nothing happened. Any other suggestions?